# How to get hibernate to print out whats wrong with a named query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

In my Spring / Hibernate / JPA application I use a lot of named queries and when I have a typo in one of those queries the see errors in my application start-up log file similar to the one below.

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: FindAllCompanyFileTypes
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:426)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:906)
    ... 70 more
```

How do configure hibernate to print out what is wrong with the named query and not just the named query has an error?

**UPDATE** for example the JPA query `SELECT f FROM Foo WHERE f.v := true` will fail with hibernate complaining that the query is invalid. Hibernate has not even tried to generate SQL from it, the query is not correct JPQL. What I want to know is how to get hibernate to say the query is wrong because := was used instead of = ? not sure if this is a setting that can be turned on in hibernate or not.

Answer (score 7):

Hibernate custom query loader stuff is located into `org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql` (for Hibernate 3 and seems that [Hibernate 4 too](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/loader/custom/sql/package-summary.html)). If using [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), it's only a matter of setting this package [its own category](http://veerasundar.com/blog/2009/08/log4j-tutorial-how-to-send-log-messages-to-different-log-files/) in order to get the logs printed (I recommend you to use the file appender because the afterwards error logs can overlap what you're interested in if using console appender).

```xml
<category name="org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql" additivity="false">
    <priority value="trace" />
    <appender-ref ref="fileAppender" />
</category>
```

Supposing your root logger displays every error in file, that's the output you get for an error while query loading:

```
17:27:18,348 TRACE SQLCustomQuery:85 -     starting processing of sql query [SELECT equipment.*, det.*
        FROM tdetectable_equipment equipment JOIN
        tdetectable det
        ON det.id = equipment.id_detectable
        WHERE
        equipment.id_detectable=det.id and det.active=1 and
        equipment.id_warehouse_container = :_Id]
17:27:18,358 TRACE SQLCustomQuery:85 -     starting processing of sql query [select line.*  from tpacking_slip_line line  join tpacking_slip slip  on line.id_packing_slip = slip.id where line.id_detectable = :detectableId and line.id_related_packing_slip_line is null and slip.`type`= :slipType order by slip.date desc;]
17:27:18,359 TRACE SQLQueryReturnProcessor:387 -     mapping alias [line] to entity-suffix [0_]
17:27:18,364 TRACE SQLCustomQuery:85 -     starting processing of sql query [select res.* from tdetectable det  join tpacking_slip_line line on det.id=line.id_detectable  and line.id_related_packing_slip_line is null join tpacking_slip slip on line.id_packing_slip = slip.id  and slip.`type`='OUT' join vreservation res on slip.id_reservation=res.id where det.id in ( :detIds ) group by(res.id) order by count(res.id) desc;]
17:27:18,365 TRACE SQLQueryReturnProcessor:387 -     mapping alias [res] to entity-suffix [0_]
17:27:18,368 ERROR SessionFactoryImpl:424 -     Error in named query: equipmentWarehouseQuery
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown collection role: com.mycompany.model.container.Container.detectables
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getCollectionPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.addCollection(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:393)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processCollectionReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:428)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.processReturn(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:358)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLQueryReturnProcessor.process(SQLQueryReturnProcessor.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.sql.SQLCustomQuery.<init>(SQLCustomQuery.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.NativeSQLQueryPlan.<init>(NativeSQLQueryPlan.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getNativeSQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:166)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(SessionFactoryImpl.java:589)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:413)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.newSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:863)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:782)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:188)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
```

That exception is being raised at loading time, but you can also have query errors while executing your code. In that case an [HibernateException](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/HibernateException.html) or similar is thrown, which you can inspect later. For the case of missing colon it is actually an [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) thrown by [AbstractQueryImpl](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/impl/AbstractQueryImpl.html) class:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No positional parameters in query: SELECT equipment.*, det.*
        FROM tdetectable_equipment equipment JOIN
        tdetectable det
        ON det.id = equipment.id_detectable
        WHERE
        equipment.id_detectable=det.id and det.active=1 and
        equipment.id_container = _Id
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on a similar problem and I discovered that, if you're using Spring Data JPA, you can use @Query in the DAO interface instead of @NamedQuery in the entity object and you get a much more detailed error message. So, instead of:

```
@Entity
@Table
@NamedQueries({@NamedQuery(name="MyEntity.myQuery" query="select blah blah blah")})
public class MyEntity
{
...
}
```

you would say

```
@Entity
@Table
public class MyEntity
{
...
}

public interface MyEntityDao
    extends JpaRepository...
{
    @Query("select blah blah blah")
    MyEntity findByMyQuery();
}
```

This uses the same query language and expressions but, for whatever quirk of implementation, delivers a much more expressive error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to print the HSQL by setting the

```
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
```

then add proper log levels in log4j to display the DEBUG or TRACE level logging for org.hibernate.*

more info here: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-logging

Comment: Show sql will print out the generated sql, that is not the issue the problem is that the JPQL query has a problem, hibernate can not parse it, so i am trying to find out how to get hibernate to explain what is wrong with a JPQL query.

Comment: Yeah i know, But looking at the HSQL is the only way to tell this. The error gets created from SessionFactoryImpl. If you look at the implementation of checkNamedQueries() in that class it is already adding errors.put(queryName, e); Query name is "FindAllCompanyFileTypes" and e in your case is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If I take a guess at what you are asking, I don't think it is hibernate that can tell you what is wrong.  The only way I have had success with this is rather painful, but at least it works!

So you need the database itself to tell you what is wrong with the query.  To do this you enable the sql output from hibernate as described above.  Then you connect to the DB via your favorite tool: squirrelSQL, toad, eclipse-plugin, etc.   Now if you don't have parameters in your sql, then you just cut and paste in there, execute the sql and it should help you debug.

If you do have parameters, the process is the same, just way more tedious!  However, once you have the SQL ok, the database should tell you what it doesn't like.  On most occasions, once you know this, it will be clear what you need to change on the hibernate side.   Every now and then it can be a mystery though, but most of those cases are documented out here!